# How do i add image/jpeg as attachment to SOAP request

Tags: java, spring, soap

I have this method, which works:

```
public <T, L> L sendRequest(T request) {

        L responseClass;
        try {
            responseClass = (L) getWebServiceTemplate()
                    .marshalSendAndReceive(uri, request,
                                           new SoapActionCallback(
                                                   uri + "/" + request.getClass().getName()));
        } catch (SoapFaultClientException ex) {
            throw new CommonException(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, "Some error", ex);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new CommonException(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, "Some error 2", ex);
        }

        return responseClass;
    }
```

Request objects are generated from wsdl.
I need to implement sending image/jpeg as attachment in SOAP request.

`public <T, L> L sendRequestWithAttachment(T request, byte[] imageData)`

I know i probably have to use AttachmentPart, but I cant find the way to make it work. Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to send attachments like this

```
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

public class ByteArrayDataSource implements javax.activation.DataSource {
    private final byte[] data;
    private final String contentType;

    public ByteArrayDataSource(byte[] data, String contentType) {
        this.data = data;
        this.contentType = contentType;
    }

    @Override
    public InputStream getInputStream() {
        return new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
    }

    @Override
    public OutputStream getOutputStream() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported");
    }

    @Override
    public String getContentType() {
        return contentType;
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "ByteArrayDataSource";
    }
}
```

```
 public <T, L> boolean sendRequestWithAttachment(T request, Class<L> responseClass, Photo attachment) {
        try {
            // Create a SOAPMessage object
            MessageFactory messageFactory = MessageFactory.newInstance();
            SOAPMessage soapMessage = messageFactory.createMessage();
            SOAPPart soapPart = soapMessage.getSOAPPart();

            // Construct the SOAP request
            SOAPEnvelope envelope = soapPart.getEnvelope();
            SOAPBody body = envelope.getBody();

            // Marshal request object
            JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(request.getClass());
            Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
            marshaller.marshal(request, body);

            // Create and add attachment parts
            String attachmentName = attachment.getFileName();
            String contentType = attachment.getPhoto().getMime();
            String finalContentType = contentType + "; name=" + attachmentName;
            byte[] attachmentBytes = attachment.getPhoto().getData();

            DataHandler dataHandler = new DataHandler(new ByteArrayDataSource(attachmentBytes, contentType));

            AttachmentPart attachmentPart = soapMessage.createAttachmentPart();
            attachmentPart.setContentId(attachmentName);
            attachmentPart.setContentType(finalContentType);
            attachmentPart.setMimeHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "binary");
            attachmentPart.setMimeHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; name=\"" + attachmentName + "\"; filename=\"" + attachmentName + "\"");
            attachmentPart.setDataHandler(dataHandler);

            soapMessage.addAttachmentPart(attachmentPart);

            // Save message changes
            soapMessage.saveChanges();

            // Set SOAP headers
            String requestContentType = "multipart/related; type=\"text/xml\"; start=\"<rootpart@soapui.org>\"";
            MimeHeaders headers = soapMessage.getMimeHeaders();
            headers.addHeader("SOAPAction", "");
            headers.addHeader("Content-Type", requestContentType);

            String credentials = userName + ":" + password;
            String encodedCredentials = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(credentials.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
            headers.addHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + encodedCredentials);

            // Send the SOAP request and receive the response
            SOAPConnectionFactory soapConnectionFactory = SOAPConnectionFactory.newInstance();
            SOAPConnection soapConnection = soapConnectionFactory.createConnection();

            SOAPMessage soapResponse = soapConnection.call(soapMessage, uri);

            // SOAP response to string
            ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            soapResponse.writeTo(out);
            String response = out.toString();

            // Close the connection
            soapConnection.close();

            // Ummarshal response to object
            ummarshalResponse(response ,responseClass);
            return true;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            return false;
        }
    }
```